# Error while starting hyperledger composer-playground

Tags: hyperledger

I am getting error dialogue "TypeError: s is undefined" after first time starting the composer ui using the command  "composer-playground" as given [here](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/stable/installing/development-tools.html)

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had exact same issue. I cleared my browser cache and history and launched login page again in the browser. It worked fine. Hope this helps.